# Why am I getting an Internal Server error

Tags: python, apache, json2html

My python script runs just fine on the Apache server locally set up on my computer, however, on importing the json2html library I am getting an internal server error

The moment I comment the import statement out , it seems to work. I even tried importing just the functions from the library , thinking maybe it is a space constraint or so.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import cgi,cgitb
 #import json2html#this has the errir
import cassandra
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
```

Internal Server Error

From logs:
ImportError: No module named json2html
[Tue Jun 11 15:42:52.495135 2019] [cgid:error] [pid 2235:tid 140698967865088] [client 127.0.0.1:35474] End of script output before headers: show.py, referer: http://test.com/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arjun/Cassandra/website_test/show.py", line 6, in 
    from json2html import *

The module works fine on my system and dosen't give any errors,but it seems to have a problem when running on the server.

Can somebody help fix this?

Comment: read server error log

Comment: Please share more details like error messages and logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server may be running under a different user. In that case, you may have installed `json2html` in a location that the Apache server user cannot access.

To check this, run a small script that prints `sys.version` both locally and in the server. If there is a mismatch, then try installing `json2html` either:

- under the Apache server user
- system-wide using `pip`

Comment: I uninstalled json2html and then ran a sudo pip , seems to have fixed the problem